# Python - Duplication of data

Tags: python, pandas

The problem that I have is the following.

I have a .CSV file where the second column has the name of substations. I read it and ask the user the name of a substation.

The idea is to take the CSV file, filter the substation and, for each circuit of that substation, find the maximum in the last column and the same with the penultimate column.

I already filter the substation and take the circuits associated to it [25-501, 25-502]. But, if I ask the program to search the maximum in the last column for each column, they duplicate the value.

I tried the next code.

```
if df_filtrado.empty:
  print("No se encontró información para la subestación especificada.")
  continue
    
else:
    subestacion_df = df_filtrado

    # Obtiene los ítems únicos de la tercera columna
    items = subestacion_df.iloc[:, 2].unique()

    for item in items:

        # Filtra por el ítem en la tercera columna
        item_df = subestacion_df[subestacion_df.iloc[:, 2] == item]

        # Encuentra el máximo de la última columna
        max_ultima_columna = item_df.iloc[:, -1].max()

        # Encuentra el máximo de la penúltima columna
        max_penultima_columna = item_df.iloc[:, -2].max()

        # Encuentra la fila que contiene el máximo de la última columna
        fila_max_ultima = item_df[item_df.iloc[:, -1] == max_ultima_columna]

        # Encuentra la fila que contiene el máximo de la penúltima columna
        fila_max_penultima = item_df[item_df.iloc[:, -2] == max_penultima_columna]

        # Combina ambas filas
        combinado = pd.concat([fila_max_ultima, fila_max_penultima])

    # Pone todo en el archivo resultados
    resultados = resultados.append(combinado, ignore_index=True)

################################################################################
### Guarda el archivo por mes
################################################################################

    # Guardar la tabla en un archivo del mes
    archivo_resultado = os.path.join(f'{ubicacion}/{subcarpeta}', f"Máximo - {subcarpeta} - {resultados.iloc[1, 1]}.csv")
    resultados.to_csv(archivo_resultado, sep=';', decimal=',', index=False)
    print(f"Se ha guardado la información del mes {subcarpeta} en {archivo_resultado} \n")
```

When i run it, the "items" variable has two variables [25-501, 25-502] but, after the line `for item in items:`, the results has duplicate items [25-501, 25-502, 25-501, 25-502]

How can i solve it?

Comment: You used `unique()` to remove duplicates when creating `items`. But `subestacion_df[subestacion_df.iloc[:, 2] == item]` uses the original df with duplicates.

Comment: Comments in code block [should be written in English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/15032126). But in this case I would advise to delete them instead of translating since they only duplicate the code. [Best practices for writing code comments](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/23/best-practices-for-writing-code-comments/).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, a quick solution would be to save `resultados.drop_duplicates()` in the csv.

And here is another possible solution of making the final DataFrame :

```
maxes = (df_filtrado.groupby("TerceraCol", as_index=False) #replace the colnames
         [["PenultimaCol", "UltimaCol"]].transform("max")) #with the actual ones

resultados = df_filtrado[df_filtrado.iloc[:, -2:].eq(maxes).all(1)] #or any ?
```

Also, be aware of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1206096).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new about programming.

I edited the question.